# Readings in allocations profile

Tags: ios, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am a little bit confused about the the readings in Instruments when I test my app with Allocations profile. The app loads pictures, then resizes them and saves in the model already small pictures. If I look at the Allocations track I can see that memory usage jumps and after pictures were resized the memory usage goes down (good), but at the same time the reading in the table view "All Allocations" remains the same 28.98 MB. So why it is like this, does it mean that my app still uses 28.98 MB?

If someone knows good articles about how to work with Instruments, please share.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Live Bytes column to see how much memory your app is currently using. In your screenshot, you're using 1.34 MB of memory, not 28.98 MB.

The Overall Bytes column tells you how much memory has been allocated since Instruments started tracing. The overall bytes value does not go down when you release memory.